# React Native - drawer not opening from menu icon and not staying open on swipe (React-Navigation v5)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am using a Minimal example of drawer-based navigation from official documentation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/). But the drawer is not opening from the hamburger menu (provided by Drawer Navigation itself) and if I swipe it to open, it opens but instantly gets closed automatically.

Edit: I am not getting any errors on console.

Here is the code from App.tsx;

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is my package.json file;

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.6",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.3.2",
    "expo-constants": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-linking": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~9.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "mobx": "^6.3.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.2.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "jest-expo": "~41.0.0-beta.0",
    "reactotron-mst": "^3.1.3",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Any luck in resolving this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ran your code its working perfectly take a look at it

https://snack.expo.dev/J7yMx0LdH

Comment: Yes its working on snack. I am not sure why it is not working in the project. I think one of the depency mentioned in package.json is causing this issue. Getting no clue how to resolve it.